# Is a Gaussian "steepest" at 1-sigma?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If I take the 2nd derivative of a Gaussian $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ and set it equal to $0$, the inflection point is $x=\pm \sigma$. Is $1$-$\sigma$ the point at which the Gaussian curve is "steepest"?

Comment: Yes, that's what inflection point means.

Comment: @NateEldredge To be sure, you could have an inflection point that satisfies $f''(x) = 0$ but the rate of change $f'(x)$ is not maximal (hence "inflection point" does not imply "steepest"); e.g., $f(x) = x^3$ at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wish to find the extrema of the derivative of $f(x)=\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$ -- those are the points with 'steepest' slope, at least locally. For a differentiable function $g$ on an open interval, its extrema satisfy $g'=0$. Hence, you should calculate the zeroes of

$$\frac{d}{dx}f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\cdot\frac{-x}{\sigma^2}\right]=\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\cdot{\left(\frac{-x}{\sigma^2}\right)}^2-\frac1{\sigma^2}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\\
=\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\cdot\left({\left(\frac{-x}{\sigma^2}\right)}^2-\frac1{\sigma^2}\right)$$

Hence, we have $\frac{d}{dx}f'(x)=0\iff {\left(\frac{-x}{\sigma^2}\right)}^2-\frac1{\sigma^2}=0\iff x^2=\sigma^2\iff x\pm\sigma$.

Well, of course we found the same values of $x$! The solutions to $(f')'=0$ are the solutions to $f''=0$. So the 'steepest' points of $f$ are a subset of the zeroes of $f''$.